# What book is the "Percy Jackson and the Sword of Hades" short story in?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, the-heroes-of-olympus

I'm trying to find the *Percy Jackson and the Sword of Hades* short story, but I can't find any references to it being in another novel. I know that it's part of the *Demigod Files* collection, but I remember reading it from the back of a different book. Does anyone remember which book it was?

Comment: He, welcome to the site. Do you recall which year (or range of years) you read this other book in?

Comment: It was somewhere in between 2013 and 2016, I think. It's kind of a broad spectrum, but I don't remember exactly when it was. I do know that the book was paperback.

Comment: The only reference to it in [ISFDb](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1066874) is in *The Demigod Files*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! It was in the paperback edition of *House of Hades*, along with the *Crown of Ptolemy* crossover short story.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably [The Trials of Apollo: The Hidden Oracle](https://www.amazon.in/Hidden-Oracle-Trials-Apollo-Book/dp/0141363932) (published in 2016, which fits the range of years you provided).

[image]

<sub>*(Image from Amazon, annotation mine)*</sub>

Percy Jackson and the Sword of Hades is present after the glossary, starting
from page 375.

Comment: Interesting.  The ISFDb entry for [that particular edition](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?568638) doesn't list the short story.